# Using a struct's member variable to compare for next_permutation()

Tags: c++, permutation

Given a struct (for example):

```
struct permutation_object
{
    int index;
    string content;
};
```

And a vector of these structs:

```
vector<permutation_object> perm_objects;
```

How can you use **int index** as a comparator for next_permutation()? The idea I'm going for is:

```
next_permutation(perm_objects.begin(), perm_objects.end(), perm_objects.permutation_object.index);
```

So given:

```
permutation_object a;
permutation_object b;
permutation_object c;

a.index = 0;
a.content = "hello ";

b.index = 1;
b.content = "world ";

c.index = 2;
c.content = "test ";

vector<permutation_object> perm_objects;
perm_objects.push_back(a);
perm_objects.push_back(b);
perm_objects.push_back(c);
```

next_permutation of perm_objects should give the order: a, c, b then b, a, c, etc. But I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to make a custom comparator or my syntax is just incorrect. Unfortunately there aren't many examples I could find for this

Comment: When Ranges come into the standard library, it's likely you'll simply be able to do `&permutation_object::index`. Some libraries offer an adapter today for use with current standard algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::next_permutation` has an overload that takes a comparison object and uses it to compare the elements of the range to get the next permutation.  You can use that overload and specify a custom camparator that will sort by only the `index`.  Using a lambda that could look like

```
vector<permutation_object> perm_objects;
// fill vector
do
{
    //stuff
} while (std::next_permutation(perm_objects.begin(), perm_objects.end(),
                               [](const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs) 
                                 { return lhs.index < rhs.index; });
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. Can you even use auto as a type for function arguments though? (Not that it's relevant to my question, was just curious)

Comment: @user3444650 You can use the in lambda's with C++14(the function is actually translated into a template function call operator).  You cannot use them with regular function.  AFAIK in C++17 you will be able to write normal functions with auto parameters.

Comment: @user3444650 If you do not have C++14 you can use `[](const perm_objects & lhs, const perm_objects & rhs){...}`